# Почему компонент не обновляется react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
        import React from "react";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import store from "./redux/store";
    import Add from "./components/AddToDo";
    
    let list = store.getState();
    
    
    window.list = list;
    
    store.subscribe(() => {
      list = store.getState();
    
      console.log(list);
    });
    
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <h1>hello</h1>
          <Add />
          <ul>
            {
              list.addToDo.map((item, index) => <li key={index} onClick={() => console.log(index)}>{item.text}</li>)
            }
          </ul>
        </Provider>
      )
    }
    
    export default App;
////////////////////////////////////////////////
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import addToDoAction from "../redux/actions/addToDo";

function Add(props) {
    let [text, setText] = React.useState("");

    const addItem = (text) =>
    {
        props.dispatch(addToDoAction(text.toString()));
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(i) => setText(i.currentTarget.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => { addItem(text); setText("") }}>add</button>
        </div>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state)
{
  return {
    todo: state
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Add);
```

Помогите решить проблему, Заранее спасибо